# MySQL comparing fields' null values with case statement

Tags: mysql, null, compare, case

I've got two simple, similar tables containing data concerning company's employee hierarchy (users and their superiors) and I would like to find the divergences between them.
Basically, they look somewhat like this:

```
 --------------------------------------
| hierarchy_id | user_id | superior_id |
 --------------------------------------
```

Everything works fine till one of the fields is null and the other from the matching table isn't.  The comparison returns `NULL`.

Any help much appreciated.

My query:

```
SELECT
    t1.user_id,
    t1.superior_id AS superior_1,
    t2.superior_id AS superior_2,
CASE
    WHEN t1.superior_id = t2.superior_id
    THEN ''
ELSE
    concat(
        t1.superior_id,
        ' != ',
        t2.superior_id
    )
END AS match_result
FROM
    dat_hierarchy_01 t1
INNER JOIN dat_hierarchy_02 t2 ON t2.hierarchy_id = t1.hierarchy_id
WHERE
    t1.superior_id != t2.superior_id
OR (
    t1.superior_id IS NULL
    AND t2.superior_id IS NOT NULL
)
OR (
    t2.superior_id IS NULL
    AND t1.superior_id IS NOT NULL
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the coalesce() function or ifnull() function in the concatenation to take care of this scenario:

```
concat(
    coalesce(t1.superior_id,'null'),
    ' != ',
    coalesce(t2.superior_id,'null')
)
```